# Applying a background color to an entire Grid row in XAML Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, xaml, background, gradient

I'm trying to apply a gradient background to just one row in a XAML Silverlight grid that I've created.

I can do something like this without any trouble:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0" />
            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Grid.Background>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- components and various stuffs -->
</Grid>
```

Unfortunately this applies the gradient to the entire grid.

It seems as though I can't apply a gradient (or even a color) to an individual row definition in the grid. Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use a [`Border`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.border(VS.95).aspx), and then use `Grid.Row` and `Grid.ColumnSpan` to put it in the specific row of the `Grid` that you want.

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition/>
       <ColumnDefinition/>
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <RowDefinition/>
       <RowDefinition/>
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>

   <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
      <Border.Background>
         <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0" />
            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1" />
         </LinearGradientBrush>
      </Border.Background>
   </Border>

   <!-- other controls in the grid -->
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks! I applied this to a similar case where I had an image background which was to be applied to more than one row, but the rows were autosized, so using an Image wasn't going to cut it, the Border works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simulate two colors in vertical order, you can also use the Offset property. If you set these two on the same value, you get this simulation:

```html
<Border.Background>
<LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="0.366" />
                <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.366" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
</Border.Background>
```

You can do even more :)

```html
<Border.Background>
   <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
     <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="0.3" />
     <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.3" />
     <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.7" />
    <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.7" />
    <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.9" />
    <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="0.9" />
  </LinearGradientBrush>
</Border.Background>
```